# How do I set the sales tax for an invoice using QuickBooks IPP v3?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm creating an invoice with multiple lines. Sales tax is set up in QuickBooks for multiple provinces. I've read through https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/global_tax_model to get an idea of how to properly integrate, but it's very confusing. I have to follow the international instructions because I am in Canada.

What I understand is that each SalesItemLineDetail gets set a TaxCode that I have to query for. How do I query for a specific GST rate? (Currently set up is GST and HST ON)

I also need tax to be exclusive. I could not find where to set this.

Do I need to add a TaxLine, or is that automatically done for me by QuickBooks?

Current snippet of my code looks like this:

```
// Set the IPP version to v3 
$IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

$Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

$Invoice->setDocNumber("DVL-".$invoice_id);
$Invoice->setTxnDate($orderdate);

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setDescription($service['name']);
$Line->setAmount($service['price']);

$orderTotal += $service['price'];

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();     
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice($service['price']);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1);
//set sales tax here?

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. At least, what I have now works.

```
$TaxCodeService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxCode();

if($property_details['province'] == "ON" || $property_details['province'] == "Ontario"){
    $tax_name = "HST ON";
} else {
    $tax_name = "GST";
}

$taxcodes = $TaxCodeService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM TaxCode WHERE name = '".$tax_name."'");

$this_tax_code = "";

foreach ($taxcodes as $TaxCode)
{
    $this_tax_code = $TaxCode->getId();
}
```

This gives me the ID of the rate that I want, and then when setting the SalesItemLineDetail simply:

```
$SalesItemLineDetail->setTaxCodeRef($this_tax_code);
```